# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect java

Tags: java

So i'm currently trying to add a `Security Certificate` that i have to the Java `Keystore`. I can do this easily on `cmd` using the value stored inside the String `temp`, but I want to be able to do this inside my java code. I'm using the following code to do it, but I get the following error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

```
    String java_Home = System.getProperty("java.home");
    java_Home = java_Home + "\\lib\\security";
    java_Home = java_Home.trim();

    String temp = "..\\..\\bin\\keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias RandomKeyName -file C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\RandomKey.crt";
    temp = temp.trim();

    String[] commands = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + java_Home, temp};

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    builder.command();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

I have looked up this error and found the following page on the error https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc956689.aspx., but i still haven't been able to solve the problem. I know it is something small but I just can't see it. Does anyone know how  to fix this?

Comment: Just to debug the issue, please provide the full path replacing "..\\..\\bin\\keytool" and execute the program. If the directory path to keytool has space on it, the cmd would fail as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- use [ProcessBuilder.directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) to set the working dir (to the location where the keytool is) and then
- in the constructor use `keytool` as the command and then the arguments to that program separately

the class documentation of the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) has a good example

Answer (score 1):

```
String temp = "..\\..\\bin\\keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias RandomKeyName -file C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\RandomKey.crt";
```

This is actually not one command, but a whole list of commands.
Add a separate array entry for each of the flags and you should be fine. Also, I don't think you need to wrap this inside a call to cmd.exe.